# using an if statement to determine whether a number is greater than one then directing output to a separate method?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for a grading System. I have got the program practically finished bar one thing. I have to determine the mark in one method and then print the mark and grade awarded using a separate method but how do i get the output from the if statements into the method to print the grade.

here is my code:

```
/*
Author: 
Title: Odds and Evens
Date created: 13/11/18
Version :1.0
*/

    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class GradeClassifier
    {
        public static void main (String[]args)
        {
            displayTitle();
            int mark = getMark();
            determineGrade(mark);
        }

    public static void displayTitle ()// prints title 
    {
        System.out.println ("Grade Classifier");
        System.out.println ("****************");
    }

    public static int getMark()// getting the mark from user
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter a mark :> ");
         return in.nextInt();
    }

    public static int determineGrade(int n1)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        if (n1 > 100){
            System.out.println ("INVALID MARK PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
            in.nextInt();
        }

        if (n1 < 100 && n1 > 70)
            System.out.print("Grade A");
        if (n1 < 69 && n1 > 60)
            System.out.print("Grade B");
        if (n1 < 59 && n1 > 50)
            System.out.println("Grade C");
        if (n1 < 49 && n1 > 40)
            System.out.println("Grade D");
        if (n1 < 40)
            System.out.println ("Grade F - Fail");

        return n1;


    }


}
```

below the last method, I have that is where I need the printResult method
any help is appreciated
thanks.
Also, I do know that using the print statements below the if statements prints out the grade but this is not how I want the program structured

Comment: Side note, the marks of 40, 50, 60, and 70 have no grade attached. Might want to use `>=` in the `if` statements.

Comment: You should also consider the case for **100** along with 40,50,60 and 70

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're just returning the input parameter.

This modified code will return a String, which contains the grade:

```
public static String determineGrade(int n1)
{

    if (n1 > 100){
        System.out.println ("INVALID MARK PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int newInput = in.nextInt();
        determineGrade(newInput);
    }

    if (n1 <= 100 && n1 >= 70)
         return "Grade A";
    if (n1 < 69 && n1 >= 60)
        return "Grade B";
    if (n1 < 59 && n1 >= 50)
        return "Grade C";
    if (n1 < 49 && n1 >= 40)
        return "Grade D";
    if (n1 < 40)
        return "Grade F - Fail";

    return "";
}
```

You could also use `System.out.println(determineGrade(input));` to directly print the grade.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the grade string as the value of a class property, then you can have a method that simply prints whatever value is in the class property at the time it's called